# When to use swApp as Object vs swApp as sldworks.sldworks?

Tags: vba, solidworksapi

I am brand new to Solidworks VBA. In Excel, I followed along the example of "Import STEP File Example (VBA)" and immediately received an error.

The dim swApp as sldworks.sldworks and set swApp = Application.Sldworks returned a Runtime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Screen shot of references used. SW version 2022:

[image: references used]

I tried opening a new Macro from within solidworks and the code showed Dim swApp as object.

Auto references using solidworks:

[image: auto references]

Can someone please shed light as to why the example code I found using sldworks.sldworks did not work?
Am i missing a library reference or an update of some sort?
Most of the example code I have found uses sldworks.sldworks. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: See this page where it indicates "Creating or Connecting to an Instance" https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/getting-started/stand-alone/connect-vbnet/

Comment: To elaborate, only the solidworks macro editor knows how to handle "Application.Sldworks". Using Excel's VBA or VB.Net, you'll have to use either CreateObject() or GetObject().

Comment: Thanks bigcrazy1. That's the help I was looking for. I appreciate it!